old tabulator's header info by autoColumns remains memory after re-create Tabulator
I used autoColumns in Tabulator 6.2 and date for weeks were set to columns automatically(image1). As a test, I executed a new Tabulator command against same table (#forecastTable) many times, I noticed the old column header information had remained in memory and the memory usage kept increasing(image2).
image1enter image description here
image2enter image description here
filtered_data = [
    {
        "category": "1_actual",
        "2015-09-01": 1,
        "2015-09-02": 2,
        "2015-09-03": 0,
        "2015-09-04": 1,
        "2015-09-05": 2,
    },
    {
        "category": "2_forecast",
        "2015-09-01": null,
        "2015-09-02": null,
        "2015-09-03": null,
        "2015-09-04": null,
        "2015-09-05": null,
        "2015-09-06": null,
    }
];
ForecastTable = new Tabulator(
'#forecastTable',
{data:filtered_data,
autoColumns: true,
selectableRows: 1,
}
);

I tried the replaceData and deleteColumn functions but it remains in memory. I would like to resolve this memory leak problem.

I was able to solve it myself. I added following code before "new Tabulator".
try {
ForecastTable.destroy();
} catch (error) {
console.error("error:", error.message);
}
ForecastTable = new Tabulator(

